# Firebase Firestore, Cloudflair SSR outbound network requests

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, cloudflare-workers, outbound

- I am using Svelte.kit, and using SSR feature for sitemap.xml & SEO related stuff
- I am using Firebase Firestore as backend
- I am using Cloudflare worker (wrangler) as deployment

All is working right locally, no problem setting env and stuff, when i saw cloudflare logs for my SSR request

```json
{
...,
"logs": [
    {
      "message": [
        "[2023-10-21T08:55:26.062Z]  @firebase/firestore:",
        "Firestore (9.22.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.\nThis typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend."
      ],
      "level": "error",
      "timestamp": 1697878526062
    }
  ],
...
}
```

seems like outbound network requests are being failed,
on quick lookup https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#simultaneous-open-connections cloudflair only allows 6 connecting at a time, shouldn't that be enough for firestore db to work?

OR is it some another problem?